# printing numbers with nested loops

Tags: java

I have to print the following numbers using nested loops, and I kinda have an idea how, but not how to execute it.

```
000111222333444555666777888999

000111222333444555666777888999

000111222333444555666777888999
```

My code so far is something like:

```
public class opgave_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int first  = 3;
        final int second    = 3;
        final int third = 9;

        for (int i = 0; i <= first ; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= second; j++) {
                for (int k = j; k <= third; k++) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to output every digit between 0 and 9 three times? Do you mean that by *print the following numbers*? What IDE are you using? Or just command line tools?

Comment: Try to think first how to print `000111222333444555666777888999` serie. What loop(s) do you need here? After that you can wrap it into another loop which will print it N times.

Comment: Have a look at your code (ideally with a debugger): you're printing `i` but have the condition `i <= first` which is restricted to `i <= 3`. Also you want to have 3 lines so your first loop should contain printing a linebreak. Then the second loop would actually represent the digits (so print `j` instead) and it probably needs to start at 0 as well. Also `k` would have to go from 0 to 2 instead of `j` to 9.

Answer (score 10):

You should proceed by steps to resolve such problem.

First, you want to print a number 3 times :

```
int myNumber = 0;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    System.out.print(myNumber);
}
```

Second, you want to repeat it 9 times and your number to vary from 0 to 9 (seems like an index of loop) :

```
for(int myNumber=0; myNumber<=9; myNumber++) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.print(myNumber);
    }
}
```

Third, you want to display this line 3 times :

```
for(intj=0; j<3; j++) {
    for(int myNumber=0; myNumber<=9; myNumber++) {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            System.out.print(myNumber);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(""); //new line
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, it's always best to look at a problem objectivly in small steps and then add always a bit more logic until it finally works. +1

Comment: Waay better then i expected, My hero!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%1$s%1$s%1$s", j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Which uses 2 nested loops. The first to print the line 3 times, and the second to print the numbers per line

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop, that loops 3 times. in that you put a loop that prints every number from 0 to 9 3 times in a row within the same line

```
for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.print(i+""+i+""+i);
    }
    System.out.println(); //for the new line
}
```

or

```
for(int a = 0; a < 3; a++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println(); //for the new line
}
```

this should do